# How to identify elements that are in shadow Dom using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, ui-automation

I used following code:

```
var listItems = element.all(by.deepCss('span'));
```

and it brings up all span elements but I want to get info of a particular span, any help is appreciated.

Comment: SHare your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.all();` will return an ElementArrayFinder, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all). Can you narrow down the selector?

Or you can use the `filter()`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter the specific element you are searching for.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for input and will look into this and keep you posted if this solution is working

Comment: let listItem = element.all(by.deepCss('span')).all(by.xpath('//span[text()="text"]'));
                   console.log("list item is :"+listItem.getText()); is returning [object,object]. am I doing correct way? please guide me

Comment: Hi Babu, protractor and webdriverjs work with promises. That means that you need to resolve the promise before you can check the output. For example: `element(by.css('#element-id')).getText().then(function (text){ console.log('text of resolved promise is: ', text});` If you never worked with promises it's good to dive into that and start reading for example this [post](https://bitsofco.de/javascript-promises-101/)